# Signed Hexadecimal Value Representation in Verilog

Tags: hex, verilog, fpga, system-verilog

apologies if this is a simple question but I am trying to extrapolate on some code and I am struggling to find the values of a few constants. Here is the relevant code below defining constants with hexadecimal values.

```
assign c = 18'sh3_8000; //-0.5 table value (50) times 0.01
assign d = 18'sh0_051E; // 0.02 table value (2) times 0.01
```

As far as I am aware they are both 18bit signed hexadecimal values. Representing the second parameter, d, in Binary:

0h51E = 000000010100011110 [To an 18 bit twos compliment binary representation]

As the first bit is 0 the number is positive so it should be equal to: 10100011110

Converting to decimal yields 1310. This multiplied by 0.01 is 13.1 which seems to have no correspondence to the 'table value' which is mentioned. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers, NZBRU.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the comments in your code, but the hex values make sense. These are *fixed point signed* numbers; in these examples, the *binary point* is two bits in from the left (where the underscore is). Therefore, the leftmost bit represents 2 or -2, the next one 1  and the next one (to the right of the binary point) represents 0.5, then 0.25 etc.

So, let's have a look at the first one first:

```
assign c = 18'sh3_8000; //-0.5 table value (50) times 0.01
```

0.5 in this representation is

```
18'sb00_1000000000000000
```

inverting all the bits and adding 1 (the way to negate a twos compliment number) gives us:

```
the binary point
       |
       V
18'sb11_0111111111111111
18'sb00_0000000000000001 +
----------------------------
18'sb11_1000000000000000
```

So `18'sb11_1000000000000000` or `18'h3_8000` represents -0.5.

Now let's look at the other number:

```
assign d = 18'sh0_051E; // 0.02 table value (2) times 0.01
```

In binary, this is `18'sb00_0000010100011110`. The right hand bit (the LSB) is the `2**-16` column. You converted the binary pattern `10100011110` to `d'1310`, so let's use that by multiplying it by `2**-16`:

```
1310 / 65536 = 0.019989013
```

which isn't as close to 0.02 as

```
1311 / 65536 = 0.020004272
```

but there you go.